# Zapier → Discord Webhook Embed Doesn't Work

Tags: discord, webhooks, zapier

What I have in the `content` field is just sent as raw text. The `username` and `avatar_url` fields work.
[Zap Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOJL9.png)
[What the webhook posts in Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEXJa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Per [the Discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message), `content` is a string that holds message text. `embed` is the key to use when passing an embed object. I think you need to replace the `content` key with `embed` and change the value to raise up the object that's currently in your `embeds` array.

Comment: Using `embed` returns error "Cannot send empty message". Using `embed` and `content` in separate fields returns only what is in the `content` field. Using `embeds` returns "Bad Request" error.

Comment: Here are the docs for [webhooks](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook), btw